# Potential return on investment in a raffle with multiple prizes

Tags: probability

Could anyone show me how to calculate my potential return on investment in a raffle with multiple prizes and ticket options?

Winning tickets do not go back into the draw.

Constants below:
Prize pool of \$3,900
Total number of tickets 190

Purchase options: 
1 for \$20 
3 for \$70 
7 for \$100

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Notice in my editing that [1] I used `<br>` to create line breaks for legibility and [2] Since `$...$` is used to create [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) expressions, in order to express (for example) \$100, you have to use the syntax of `\$100`.

Comment: Thankyou for the edit!

Comment: Suppose that you purchase $n$ tickets, where $n \in \{1,2,\cdots,190\}.$  For $n = 190$, your expected return on the investment would be $$\frac{n}{190} \times \$3900 ~: ~n = 190.$$  In such a scenario, each of the $190$ tickets purchased **has the same value**.  So, how much is each ticket worth?